# $p^2-p+1$ is a perfect cube of a prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, perfect-powers

Determine with a proof all prime numbers p such that p$^2$-p+1 is a cube of a prime number.
By trial and error method 19$^2$-19+1=7$^3$
Is it the only p?
How should I prove it?

Comment: More generally, all integer solutions of $x^2+x+1=y^3$ are known: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394240

Comment: My answer helped you?

Comment: Really. Thank you very much

Comment: Related [How to solve $p^2 - p + 1 = q^3$ over primes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2158364/how-to-solve-p2-p-1-q3-over-primes), and [quadratic diophantine involving primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2014989/quadratic-diophantine-involving-primes). And also this AoS forum thread: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h35935p224998

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **HINT** It can be rewritten as $$p_{1}(p_{1}-1) = (p_{2}-1)(p_{2}^2+p_{2}+1) $$
  If you rewrite as: $ (p_{1}-1) = k(p_{2}-1),$ then everything reduces to a solution to the given equation:
  $$(k y - k + 1) k = y^2 + y + 1$$
  I myself, unfortunately, could not solve this equation, but if to believe WolframAlf, its integer solution $ (k = 3; y = 1), (k = 3; y = 7) $

Comment: $ gcd(p_1, p_2-1) = ...? $

Comment: I think you will understand what happens if you write your solution like this: $19*(19-1) = (7-1)(7^2+7+1)$

Comment: I proved that it should be 1 but still no proof

Comment: If their common divisor is 1, what follows from this?

Comment: That the other factor of R.H.S. should be divisible by P1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77144/discussion-between-vladislav-kharlamov-and-thishanka-alahakoon).

Comment: I don't see it yet, either. At best, it follows that $7$ is a cube root, hence $19\equiv 1\pmod 6$

Comment: I don’t see it as well. Please elaborate.

Comment: Theoretically, the last equation should not be difficult to solve and I have some ideas, but without the proper experience, I do not want to assert the correctness of my thoughts